# Array is only showing the first value when compared

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array from a post that holds a couple values and am trying to do a compare to see if the array contains certain strings.

like this:

```
if ($q->param('tradesFour[]') =~ m/Steel/)
```

the datadump of the array looks like this:

```
'tradesFour[]' => [
  'Street/Road',
  'Steel Erection'
],
```

but when I do this the if statement is not true, also when i print tradesFour[] it just gives me the first value. How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: What is `$q`? It must be an object that accepts the `param` method.

Comment: @Borodin my `$q = CGI->new();`

Comment: "Steel Erection"? <Insert off-color joke here>

Comment: what are you dumping that shows that datadump?  also, show the code you are using to "print tradesFour[]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scalar context, `CGI::param` will only ever return the first parameter value. You have to put in list context to retrieve all of them.

You could write your test like this

```
if (grep /Steel/, $q->param('tradesFour[]')) { ... }
```

in which checks all the values in the list and returns the number of them that match the regex.

Comment: wouldn't you need an Array for grep to match properly ?

Comment: `grep` requires a list. `CGI::param` returns a list of values when it is called in list context.

Comment: (In fact, in scalar context, it can't possibly return anything but a single value)

Comment: @ikegami: Yes of course. I was meaning a single *param* value. Fixed.